# JQuery, javascript, Each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have inputs hidden from `PHP` and I'm corventing it into `javascript` `array`. Now I need some function in `jQuery` like

```
$(".data").attr('data-day'== day).each(function(){});
```

I need this solution, no others... Thanks!

Comment: show the relevant html. What is `day`? How do you hide something from php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's how you do it](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$(".data[data-day='" + day + "']").each(function() { 
    ...
});
```

Comment: I think you should treat day as variable.